# Sidebar collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

my code is similar to this.. https://medium.com/@ratheesh.archal/sidebar-menu-in-react-with-material-ui-d99747f90f1f

im a newbie
trying to implement a sidebar collapse on material-ui
but cant able to figure out ..
I dont know what im doing wrong

There is big explanation on material-ui about minipersistent drawer
seems like i cant fit that code into this..

```
    import React, {  useState, forwardRef } from 'react';
    import {List, ListItem, Collapse, Button, Drawer } from '@material-ui/core';
    import clsx from 'clsx';
    import { ExpandLess, ExpandMore } from "@material-ui/icons";
    import menuItems from './sideBarItems';
    import { NavLink as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
    import useStyles from './menuBarStyles';
    const MenuBar = (props) => {
        const [ menu, setMenu ] = useState({});
        const { className, ...rest } = props;
        const classes  = useStyles();
        const handleClick = (item) => {
            let newData = {...menu, [item] : !menu[item]};
            setMenu(newData);
        }
        const CustomRouterLink = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
          <div ref={ref} style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <RouterLink {...props} />
          </div>
        ));
        const handleMenu = ( children, level=0 ) => {
            return children.map(({children, name, url, links }) => {
                if ( !children ) {
                  return (
                    <List component="div" disablePadding key={ name }>
                      <ListItem
                        className={classes.item}
                        disableGutters
                        style={{padding:"0px"}}
                        key={name}
                      >
                        <Button
                          className={clsx({
                            [classes.btnRoot] : true,
                            [classes.button] : true,
                            [classes.subMenu] : level
                          })}
                          component={CustomRouterLink}
                          to={url}
                        >
                          {name}
                        </Button>
                      </ListItem>
                    </List>
                  )
                }
                return (
                  <div key={ name }>
                  <ListItem
                    className={classes.item}
                    disableGutters
                    key={name}
                    onClick={() => handleClick(name)}
                  >
                    <Button
                    className={clsx({
                      [classes.btnRoot] : true,
                      [classes.button] : true,
                      [classes.subMenu] : level
                    })}>
                      { name } { menu[ name ] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                      </Button>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Collapse
                      in={ (menu[name]) ? true : false }
                      timeout="auto"
                      unmountOnExit
                    >
                      { handleMenu( children, 1) }
                    </Collapse>
                  </div>
                )
            })
        }
    return (
          <Drawer
              anchor="left"
              classes={{ paper: classes.drawer }}
              open={true}
              variant="persistent"
            >
              <List {...rest} className={clsx(classes.root, className)} >
                  { handleMenu(menuItems.data) }
              </List>
          </Drawer>
       )
    }
    export default MenuBar;
```